# Iterating over words in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I have array of words in .data

```
array: .word 0x0000012, 0x0000d42f, ..... , 0 // 0 indicates end of array.
```

I need to print each word's count of '1's and then at the end print the maximum count of '1's .

I tried moving the word to a temporary register and then shift it left, each iteration, but it doesn't work ..

```
################### Data segment ###################
.data
    x: .word 0x00000001, 0x00000007, 0x0000ffff, 0x20430066, 0
    bits: .word 0
################### Code segment ###################
.text
.globl main
  main:

    lw $a0, x
    li $v0,1
    syscall

    li $v0,10 # exit
    syscall
```

That code works. but it only refers to the first word in x. 
I don't know how to get to the second WORD in x

Comment: Please add your actual assembly code to your question.

Comment: @TrippKinetics , I've edited my post. Thank you

Comment: You probably want to load the *address*  of `x` into a register, via `la $reg, x`, then successively load form that address `lw $otherreg, 0($reg)`, and increment the address `addi $reg, $reg, 4`. Finding the popcount is *your* homework, but I know it can be frustrating to get started.